# Hidden element, 1 sec delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, attributes

I have a div element that I want to hide if the value of the option list is not equal to 1. I'm using the jquery to hide/show the element.

```
   if ($("#prov").val() == "0") {
       $("#label1").hide();
       $("#list1").hide();
   } else {
       $("#label1").show();
       $("#list1").show();
   }
```

However, there's always I sec delay before it hides the element if the value is equal to 0. My HTML code is at the beginning and my javascrip/jquery code is at the end because I can't hide/show the element if it hasn't been created yet.

Also, I tried to use the hidden property in CSS but I get the same result.

```
hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

Below are the div elements.

```
<div>
    <label>Location:</label>
    <div>
        <select class="form-control" id="label1">
            <option label=" "></option>
            <option value="1">Canada</option>
            <option value="0">Other</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <label id="list1">Province:</label>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option value="  "> </option>
            <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
            <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
            <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
            <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
            <option value="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
            <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
            <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
            <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
            <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
            <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
            <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
            <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
            <option value="YT">Yukon</option>
        </select>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The delay you're talking about is called the FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content) and occurs when you update the UI in the doc ready or, in this case, at the bottom - via javascript.  The answer is to build your HTML using the values rather than change your UI after it's rendered.  So it depends on how you build your HTML and where you get your initial values from (eg you don't show how you build `#prov`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay was cause, because my JavaScrip/JQuery was included at the end of my file.

> **A FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content)** is an instance where a web page
>   appears briefly with the browser's default styles prior to loading an
>   external file, due to the web browser engine rendering the page before
>   all information is retrieved.The page corrects itself as soon as the
>   style rules are loaded and applied; however the shift may be
>   distracting.
>
> Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content

The solution I found for this issue is to hide the body of the web page until the entire page (including the JavaScript/JQuery files) is loaded. Once everything is loaded, it will display the body section at the same time, which will eliminate the delay:

Hide the body section:

`<body style="visibility: hidden;" onload="js_Load()">`

> The visibility property specifies whether or not an element is
>   visible.

Write a JavaScript function `js_Load()` that contains the following:

```
document.body.style.visibility='visible';
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass in the value

`.show(0)`

This will prevent any of the default delays between hiding and showing.  The default is set for 400 milliseconds.

duration (default: 400)

https://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: Thanks for the information but there is still a delay, because it loads the DOM first then it execute my jquery.